# Religious Group Sends Man to the Past, Man Ends up Being Their Messiah

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel, religion

This is a fairly recent short story perhaps written within the past ten years. As far as I know it's not by any major author and was posted on reddit or 4chan or something.

A religious group has developed time travel and is sending a man to the past to study their Messiah or some such. The man is preparing for his journey with prayer or reading their holy book.

He is successfully sent to the past, but the rest of his group is not there. He does the work he is assigned alone, spreading stories of his faith. A woman eventually stays with him and he has a family. He develops a following and slowly comes to the realization that the man he came to study is him.

In the end, he does not feel bitterness and is perhaps a little happy. He buries his dog tags or something similar and includes his mission diary for the people of the future to find.

Comment: [First result on Google for `man time travels becomes religious`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behold_the_Man_(novel)) may be of interest. It's not recent and doesn't quite match but otherwise has very similar plot elements. If nothing else you can read this one instead. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I actually found that while searching as well and bookmarked to read later.

Comment: @MrLister Oh yes, that's the one! I totally forgot it was a comic.

Comment: Asimov's [The End of Eternity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_End_of_Eternity) employs a similar subplot, but maybe the idea is just too generic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is [*The Mission*](http://www.viruscomix.com/page564.html) by Winston Rowntree on VirusComix.

> This is a fairly recent short story perhaps written within the past ten years. As far as I know it's not by any major author and was posted on reddit or 4chan or something.

On his own site actually, in 2012.

> A religious group has developed time travel and is sending a man to the past to study their Messiah or some such. The man is preparing for his journey with prayer or reading their holy book.

[image]

> He is successfully sent to the past, but the rest of his group is not there. He does the work he is assigned alone, spreading stories of his faith.

[image]

A woman eventually stays with him and he has a family. He develops a following and slowly comes to the realization that the man he came to study is him.

[image]

> In the end, he does not feel bitterness and is perhaps a little happy. He buries his dog tags or something similar and includes his mission diary for the people of the future to find.

[image]

All images taken from the site, and used for identification purposes only. No copyright infringement intended.